# How to implement partial search floats in Prisma?

Tags: prisma

I'm trying to implement a search query in Prisma for a float.  Right now I'm using equals, but that means you have to type the exact number.  I'd like to implement something like a partial string search - i.e. if I type in '36' it would bring back '360' or '23.36'

The only options I see are greater than or less than or equals - how do you handle number searches?  I would be OK even if it only had 'starts with' logic, so I could get back 36 or 362 or 3612, but I can't figure out any way to accomplish this.

Is there any way to achieve this with Prisma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to accomplish something like this that I could see is to use String as the type within Prisma schema and within your code consume the values by parsing them into floats again / stringifying them.

This way you could use string operators within Prisma, so for example `{ floatAsString: { contains: '36' } }` would find `360` and `23.36`

If you keep it as floats in the Prisma schema there are no operators to achieve this in the Prisma API.